# What does the pyspark.sql.functions.window function's 'startTime' argument do and window.start?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, window

The example is as follows:

```py
df=spark.createDataFrame([
    (1,"2017-05-15 23:12:26",2.5),
    (1,"2017-05-09 15:26:58",3.5),
    (1,"2017-05-18 15:26:58",3.6),
    (2,"2017-05-15 15:24:25",4.8),
    (3,"2017-05-25 15:14:12",4.6)],["index","time","val"]).orderBy("index","time")
df.collect()
```

```
+-----+-------------------+---+
|index|               time|val|
+-----+-------------------+---+
|    1|2017-05-09 15:26:58|3.5|
|    1|2017-05-15 23:12:26|2.5|
|    1|2017-05-18 15:26:58|3.6|
|    2|2017-05-15 15:24:25|4.8|
|    3|2017-05-25 15:14:12|4.6|
+-----+-------------------+---+
```

for the function "pyspark.sql.functions"

```
window(timeColumn, windowDuration, slideDuration=None, startTime=None)

timeColumn：The time column must be of TimestampType.

windowDuration：  Durations are provided as strings, e.g. '1 second', '1 day 12 hours', '2 minutes'. Valid
interval strings are 'week', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'millisecond', 'microsecond'.

slideDuration: If the 'slideDuration' is not provided, the windows will be tumbling windows.

startTime： the startTime is the offset with respect to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC with which to start window intervals. For example, in order to have hourly tumbling windows that start 15 minutes past the hour, e.g. 12:15-13:15, 13:15-14:15... provide `startTime` as `15 minutes`.
```

I want to count the parameters "val" in this function for every 5 days, and I set the parameter "slideDuration" a string value with "5 day"

```
timeColumn="time",windowDuration="5 day",slideDuration="5 day"
```

the codes as follows:

```py
df2=df.groupBy("index",F.window("time",windowDuration="5 day",slideDuration="5 day")).agg(F.sum("val").alias("sum_val"))
```

When I get the value of the parameter "window.start", the time didn't start with the minimal time I give in the column "time" or the time I've set before,but the other time from no where.

The results came out as follows:

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|index|start                |end                  |sum_val|
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|1    |2017-05-09 08:00:00.0|2017-05-14 08:00:00.0|3.5    |
|1    |2017-05-14 08:00:00.0|2017-05-19 08:00:00.0|6.1    |
|2    |2017-05-14 08:00:00.0|2017-05-19 08:00:00.0|4.8    |
|3    |2017-05-24 08:00:00.0|2017-05-29 08:00:00.0|4.6    |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

When I set a value for the parameter "startTime" with '0 second'(the codes are as follows):

```py
df2=df.groupBy("index",F.window("time",windowDuration="5 day",slideDuration="5 day",startTime="0 second")).agg(F.sum("val").alias("sum_val"))
```

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|index|start                |end                  |sum_val|
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
|1    |2017-05-09 08:00:00.0|2017-05-14 08:00:00.0|3.5    |
|1    |2017-05-14 08:00:00.0|2017-05-19 08:00:00.0|6.1    |
|2    |2017-05-14 08:00:00.0|2017-05-19 08:00:00.0|4.8    |
|3    |2017-05-24 08:00:00.0|2017-05-29 08:00:00.0|4.6    |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-------+
```

The results came out that it still didn't start with the minimal time in the column "time"

So how should I make this function start with the minimal time in the column "time",or the time I set at the first time,such as"2017-05-09 15:25:30",I'm so thankful for you to figure me out of this question

The official introduction of the 'startTime' as follows

```
The startTime is the offset with respect to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC with which to start window intervals. 
For example, in order to have hourly tumbling windows that start 15 minutes past the hour, e.g. 12:15-13:15, 13:15-14:15...
provide `startTime` as `15 minutes`.
```

### References are as follows

1.[What does the 'pyspark.sql.functions.window' function's 'startTime' argument do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541446/what-does-the-pyspark-sql-functions-window-functions-starttime-argument-do)

2.https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/12008

3.http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.functions.window

Answer (score 5):

The problem you experience is completely unrelated to `startTime` and has two components:

- Spark's [timestamp semantics](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/SQL-TIMESTAMP-semantics-vs-SPARK-18350-td21621.html) where timestamps are always handled in respect to local timezone. Based on the offset shown in the output we conclude that JVM uses GMT+8 or equivalent timezone. Please consider these two scenarios:

  ```
  >>> from pyspark.sql.functions import window
  >>>
  >>> spark.conf.get("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions")
  '-Duser.timezone=GMT+8'
  >>> spark.conf.get("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions")
  '-Duser.timezone=GMT+8'
  >>> str(spark.sparkContext._jvm.java.util.TimeZone.getDefault())
  'sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+08:00",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]'
  >>>
  >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"2017-05-15 23:12:26",2.5)], ["index","time","val"])
  >>> (df
  ...     .withColumn("w", window("time" ,windowDuration="5 days" ,slideDuration="5 days"))
  ...     .show(1, False))
  ...     
  +-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------+
  |index|time               |val|w                                            |
  +-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------+
  |1    |2017-05-15 23:12:26|2.5|[2017-05-14 08:00:00.0,2017-05-19 08:00:00.0]|
  +-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------+
  ```

  vs.

  ```
  >>> from pyspark.sql.functions import window
  >>>
  >>> spark.conf.get("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions")
  '-Duser.timezone=UTC'
  >>> spark.conf.get("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions")
  '-Duser.timezone=UTC'
  >>> str(spark.sparkContext._jvm.java.util.TimeZone.getDefault())
  'sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]'
  >>>
  >>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,"2017-05-15 23:12:26",2.5)], ["index","time","val"])
  >>> (df
  ...     .withColumn("w", window("time" ,windowDuration="5 days" ,slideDuration="5 days"))
  ...     .show(1, False))
  ... 
  +-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------+
  |index|time               |val|w                                            |
  +-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------+
  |1    |2017-05-15 23:12:26|2.5|[2017-05-14 00:00:00.0,2017-05-19 00:00:00.0]|
  +-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------+
  ```

  As you can see output is adjusted according to local timezone, while input string is parsed as UTC timestamp.
- `window` semantics. If you take a look at the execution plan

  ```
  >>> df.withColumn("w", window("time",windowDuration="5 days",slideDuration="5 days")).explain(False)
  == Physical Plan ==
  *Project [index#21L, time#22, val#23, window#68 AS w#67]
  +- *Filter (((isnotnull(time#22) && isnotnull(window#68)) && (cast(time#22 as timestamp) >= window#68.start)) && (cast(time#22 as timestamp) < window#68.end))
     +- *Expand [List(named_struct(start, ((((CEIL((cast((precisetimestamp(cast(time#22 as timestamp)) - 0) as double) / 4.32E11)) + 0) - 1) * 432000000000) + 0), end, ((((CEIL((cast((precisetimestamp(cast(time#22 as timestamp)) - 0) as double) / 4.32E11)) + 0) - 1) * 432000000000) + 432000000000)), index#21L, time#22, val#23), List(named_struct(start, ((((CEIL((cast((precisetimestamp(cast(time#22 as timestamp)) - 0) as double) / 4.32E11)) + 1) - 1) * 432000000000) + 0), end, ((((CEIL((cast((precisetimestamp(cast(time#22 as timestamp)) - 0) as double) / 4.32E11)) + 1) - 1) * 432000000000) + 432000000000)), index#21L, time#22, val#23)], [window#68, index#21L, time#22, val#23]
        +- Scan ExistingRDD[index#21L,time#22,val#23]
  ```

  and focus on as single component:

  ```
  ((((CEIL((cast((precisetimestamp(cast(time#22 as timestamp)) - 0) as double) / 4.32E11)) + 0) - 1) * 432000000000)
  ```

  you'll see that window takes a ceiling of the numeric value effectively truncating timestamp to whole intervals.

Finally `startTime` in

```
df.groupBy("index",F.window("time",windowDuration="5 day",slideDuration="5  day",startTime="0 second"))
```

has no effect at all, because it behaves like default (no offset). If anything you can try:

```
(startTime, ) = (df
    .select(min_(col("time").cast("timestamp")).alias("ts"))
    .select(
       ((col("ts").cast("double") - 
       col("ts").cast("date").cast("timestamp").cast("double")
      ) * 1000).cast("integer"))
     .first())

w = window(
    "time", 
    windowDuration="5 days",
    slideDuration="5 days",
    startTime="{} milliseconds".format(startTime))


df.withColumn("w", w).show(1, False)
```

```
+-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------+
|index|time               |val|w                                            |
+-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------+
|1    |2017-05-15 23:12:26|2.5|[2017-05-14 23:12:26.0,2017-05-19 23:12:26.0]|
+-----+-------------------+---+---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thank you very much, your answer is clear and logical."startTime" is a offset value

Comment: Thanks a lot! First with a proper explanation and solution.

I faced a problem where my daily aggregates over a window always started from 01:00 to 01:00. I quickly realised this was a timezone issue (as I'm GMT+1), but it took me a while to find a proper solution.

Final solution was to set the Spark session config to UTC default, so times are never adjusted:
`spark= (SparkSession.builder\
.config('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=GMT') \
.config('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Duser.timezone=GMT') \
.config('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')
.getOrCreate())`