# How does Spark determine window.start for first window when grouping by time window used?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Here's data example:

```
scala> purchases.show(false)
+---------+-------------------+--------+
|client_id|transaction_ts     |store_id|
+---------+-------------------+--------+
|1        |2018-06-01 12:17:37|1       |
|1        |2018-06-02 13:17:37|2       |
|1        |2018-06-03 14:17:37|3       |
|1        |2018-06-09 10:17:37|2       |
|2        |2018-06-02 10:17:37|1       |
|2        |2018-06-02 13:17:37|2       |
|2        |2018-06-08 14:19:37|3       |
|2        |2018-06-16 13:17:37|2       |
|2        |2018-06-17 14:17:37|3       |
+---------+-------------------+--------+
```

when I grouping by time window:

```
scala> purchases.groupBy($"client_id", window($"transaction_ts", "8 days")).count.orderBy("client_id", "window.start")show(false)

+---------+---------------------------------------------+-----+                 
|client_id|window                                       |count|
+---------+---------------------------------------------+-----+
|1        |[2018-05-28 17:00:00.0,2018-06-05 17:00:00.0]|3    |
|1        |[2018-06-05 17:00:00.0,2018-06-13 17:00:00.0]|1    |
|2        |[2018-05-28 17:00:00.0,2018-06-05 17:00:00.0]|2    |
|2        |[2018-06-05 17:00:00.0,2018-06-13 17:00:00.0]|1    |
|2        |[2018-06-13 17:00:00.0,2018-06-21 17:00:00.0]|2    |
+---------+---------------------------------------------+-----+
```

**I'm wondering why the first `window.start` is `2018-05-28 17:00:00.0` whereas minimal value in data is `2018-06-01 12:17:37`?**

How does Spark calculates time windows? I was expecting that first smallest value will be used as `min window.start`...

Comment: [What does the pyspark.sql.functions.window function's 'startTime' argument do and window.start?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48351951/8371915)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @user8371915!

Following suggested links I found answer that I was looking for, in particular `window.start` has nothing with my data, Spark generates window starting from `1970-01-01`. Refer for more details in [What does the 'pyspark.sql.functions.window' function's 'startTime' argument do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41541446/what-does-the-pyspark-sql-functions-window-functions-starttime-argument-do)